# Leibniz's notation finding: the change in the area of a square

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have been  going through the applications of derivatives  and I  found that we can find the change in the area based on the change in the one side.

Area of a square $A(x) = x^2$, and it says $\frac{dA}{dx} = 2x$, $dA = 2x \,dx$, but how? The rule is $\lim\limits_{dx\to0} \frac{dA}{dx}$.

I just could not find the connection between these two.

Comment: If $A(x)=x^2$, we want to know the change in the area when $x \to x+\Delta x$. $A(x+\Delta x)-A(x)=(x+\Delta x)^2-x^2=\Delta x (2x + \Delta x)$. So...

Comment: If $dA/dx$ is actually Leibniz notation then it makes no sense to write $\lim_{dx\to0} dA/dx$. Instead, you might write $dA/dx = \lim_{\Delta x\to0} \Delta A/\Delta x$.

Comment: @AnuragA That looks like an answer.

Comment: so we can not write deltaA/deltaX  = 2XdeltaX

Comment: my question is is deltaX and dX are the same?

Comment: if they are different , then we can not write  ΔA = Δx2x since  ΔA is not dA and Δx is not dx

Comment: is there any difference  between x→x+Δx  and x+Δx→x